# How to resolve weird 404 error while connecting to php-fpm via nginx (reverse proxy) inside of a podman pod?

Tags: php, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, podman, nextcloud

## Problem

I have recently migrated my `docker-compose.yml` (Arch Linux host) to podman running via systemd services (nixos host - `virtualisation.oci-containers`).

I have multiple services (gitlab, phpmyadmin etc.) running without any issues for a few months since the migration.

My nextcloud-fpm however isn't working as expected.

### Details

The first connection to nextcloud-fpm works and a web page is displayed correctly. I can log in, upload files etc.

After I reload the page (or sometimes after multiple reloads/reopens) I do however just get a blank page and can't interact with the server at all.

I do still get emails from my nextcloud server, which means that it is still up and seemingly working correctly. I just have no access to the web interface at all and also can't log in via app etc.

## Overview: Connection handling

### Working services' connections are handled like this

`Cloudflare (proxied) -> Reverse proxy (nginx) -> service` (*proxy_pass is used to connect to the service*)

### nextcloud-fpm is handled like this

`Cloudflare (proxied) -> Reverse proxy (nginx) -> Web server (nginx) -> service` (*fastcgi_pass is used to connect to the service*)

## Additional info

I use the following images for the containers:

- Reverse proxy & Nextcloud web server: `docker.io/nginx:stable-alpine`
- Nextcloud app: `docker.io/nextcloud:stable-fpm-alpine`

The following sections include extensive configs and logs. It might be a bit much, but since I can't figure out what is really relevant here, I just included everything.

The following is very interesting: 12:36:43 is the last logged entry in the webserver and the nextcloud app, with 2 resulting in 404 at the end. The reverse proxy however still logs multiple connection attempts afterwards (logged until 12:46:44), all resulting in 404.

To me this means that the Nginx web server is either busy or just unaccessible after the first few interactions and I can't tell why.

In the setup I used before (`docker-compose.yml`) with the same configs, everything worked flawlessly. The biggest difference between the two is the following: Reverse proxy, Nextcloud web server and Nextcloud app share the same network namespace. This is because they are in the same podman pod, which allows them to communicate via 127.0.0.1.

### Configs

INFO: Domains have been obfuscated.

[*reverse-proxy.conf (Reverse proxy - only relevant section)*](https://pastebin.com/CAciBrL9)

INFO: This mostly matches [the official instructions](https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/latest/admin_manual/installation/nginx.html) for nginx

[*nextcloud.foo.tld.conf (Nextcloud web server)*](https://pastebin.com/49YCV8qu)

#### Additional configs (for include)

[*/etc/nginx/conf.d/redirect.conf*](https://pastebin.com/DGxfFidL)

INFO: Some info has been obfuscated (???)

[*/etc/nginx/conf.d/ssl.conf*](https://pastebin.com/vSQjeHTk)

[*/etc/nginx/conf.d/common.conf*](https://pastebin.com/K9jZrytV)

[*/etc/nginx/conf.d/common-location.conf*](https://pastebin.com/GTiewuka)

### Logs

INFO: Public ips here are cloudflare ips that the traffic is routed through.

*podman-reverse-proxy.log (Reverse proxy)*

```
-- Boot 1d3092f508084a6ea6c9b197802b6781 --
Mar 20 12:35:48 cyan systemd[1]: Starting podman-reverse-proxy.service...
[...]
Mar 20 12:35:50 cyan systemd[1]: Started podman-reverse-proxy.service.
[...]
Mar 20 12:36:28 cyan reverse-proxy[2878]: 172.71.182.77 - - [20/Mar/2024:12:36:28 +0000] "GET /index.php/204 HTTP/2.0" 204 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux) mirall/3.12.0git (Nextcloud, arch-6.6.19-1-lts ClientArchitecture: x86_64 OsArchitecture: x86_64)"
Mar 20 12:36:28 cyan reverse-proxy[2878]: 172.71.98.156 - - [20/Mar/2024:12:36:28 +0000] "GET /index.php/204 HTTP/2.0" 204 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux) mirall/3.12.0git (Nextcloud, arch-6.6.19-1-lts ClientArchitecture: x86_64 OsArchitecture: x86_64)"
Mar 20 12:36:28 cyan reverse-proxy[2878]: 172.71.98.156 - - [20/Mar/2024:12:36:28 +0000] "GET /status.php HTTP/2.0" 200 140 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux) mirall/3.12.0git (Nextcloud, arch-6.6.19-1-lts ClientArchitecture: x86_64 OsArchitecture: x86_64)"
Mar 20 12:36:28 cyan reverse-proxy[2878]: 172.71.98.156 - - [20/Mar/2024:12:36:28 +0000] "GET / HTTP/2.0" 302 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux) mirall/3.12.0git (Nextcloud, arch-6.6.19-1-lts ClientArchitecture: x86_64 OsArchitecture: x86_64)"
Mar 20 12:36:28 cyan reverse-proxy[2878]: 172.71.103.171 - - [20/Mar/2024:12:36:28 +0000] "GET /ocs/v2.php/cloud/capabilities?format=json HTTP/2.0" 200 368 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux) mirall/3.12.0git (Nextcloud, arch-6.6.19-1-lts ClientArchitecture: x86_64 OsArchitecture: x86_64)"
Mar 20 12:36:28 cyan reverse-proxy[2878]: 172.70.47.93 - - [20/Mar/2024:12:36:28 +0000] "PROPFIND /remote.php/dav/files/leo/ HTTP/2.0" 401 557 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux) mirall/3.12.0git (Nextcloud, arch-6.6.19-1-lts ClientArchitecture: x86_64 OsArchitecture: x86_64)"
Mar 20 12:36:28 cyan reverse-proxy[2878]: 172.71.103.175 - - [20/Mar/2024:12:36:28 +0000] "GET /hosting/capabilities HTTP/2.0" 404 68 "-" "Nextcloud Server Crawler"
Mar 20 12:36:28 cyan reverse-proxy[2878]: 172.71.98.156 - - [20/Mar/2024:12:36:28 +0000] "GET /login HTTP/2.0" 200 5230 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux) mirall/3.12.0git (Nextcloud, arch-6.6.19-1-lts ClientArchitecture: x86_64 OsArchitecture: x86_64)"
Mar 20 12:36:29 cyan reverse-proxy[2878]: 172.71.98.156 - - [20/Mar/2024:12:36:29 +0000] "POST /index.php/login/v2 HTTP/2.0" 200 320 "-" "tulip (Desktop Client - Linux)"
Mar 20 12:36:32 cyan reverse-proxy[2878]: 172.71.102.130 - - [20/Mar/2024:12:36:32 +0000] "GET /login/v2/flow/ChPehj88Ez6kzHrrfrcHMM572RXtgtl1IohaqeJr8ObTQq40yyV9xx0NbmRwEqmhmyqMOPB3owFWjZlcXGbHhpTztZpkb6KGWC8suDWhq6Hy6R2OjJU5jYdKAcWJzrh6 HTTP/2.0" 303 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; rv:123.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/123.0"
Mar 20 12:36:32 cyan reverse-proxy[2878]: 172.71.102.130 - - [20/Mar/2024:12:36:32 +0000] "GET /login/v2/flow?user= HTTP/2.0" 200 7163 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; rv:123.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/123.0"
Mar 20 12:36:32 cyan reverse-proxy[2878]: 172.71.183.32 - - [20/Mar/2024:12:36:32 +0000] "GET /core/css/login/authpicker.css?v=6fc993ab-1 HTTP/2.0" 200 233 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; rv:123.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/123.0"
Mar 20 12:36:32 cyan reverse-proxy[2878]: 172.71.102.138 - - [20/Mar/2024:12:36:32 +0000] "GET /core/js/login/authpicker.js?v=6fc993ab-1 HTTP/2.0" 200 265 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; rv:123.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/123.0"
Mar 20 12:36:32 cyan reverse-proxy[2878]: 172.71.103.185 - - [20/Mar/2024:12:36:32 +0000] "GET /apps/theming/theme/default.css?plain=1&v=356a192b HTTP/2.0" 200 1087 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; rv:123.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/123.0"
Mar 20 12:36:32 cyan reverse-proxy[2878]: 172.71.99.105 - - [20/Mar/2024:12:36:32 +0000] "GET /apps/theming/theme/light.css?plain=1&v=356a192b HTTP/2.0" 200 1087 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; rv:123.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/123.0"
Mar 20 12:36:32 cyan reverse-proxy[2878]: 172.71.98.25 - - [20/Mar/2024:12:36:32 +0000] "GET /apps/theming/theme/opendyslexic.css?plain=0&v=356a192b HTTP/2.0" 200 336 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; rv:123.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/123.0"
Mar 20 12:36:32 cyan reverse-proxy[2878]: 172.71.99.12 - - [20/Mar/2024:12:36:32 +0000] "GET /apps/theming/theme/light-highcontrast.css?plain=0&v=356a192b HTTP/2.0" 200 1159 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; rv:123.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/123.0"
Mar 20 12:36:32 cyan reverse-proxy[2878]: 172.70.47.54 - - [20/Mar/2024:12:36:32 +0000] "GET /apps/theming/theme/dark-highcontrast.css?plain=0&v=356a192b HTTP/2.0" 200 1190 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; rv:123.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/123.0"
Mar 20 12:36:32 cyan reverse-proxy[2878]: 172.71.99.47 - - [20/Mar/2024:12:36:32 +0000] "GET /apps/theming/theme/dark.css?plain=0&v=356a192b HTTP/2.0" 200 1098 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; rv:123.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/123.0"
Mar 20 12:36:32 cyan reverse-proxy[2878]: 172.71.99.58 - - [20/Mar/2024:12:36:32 +0000] "GET /apps/theming/theme/light.css?plain=0&v=356a192b HTTP/2.0" 200 1111 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; rv:123.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/123.0"
Mar 20 12:36:33 cyan reverse-proxy[2878]: 141.101.76.89 - - [20/Mar/2024:12:36:33 +0000] "GET /apps/theming/theme/light-highcontrast.css?plain=1&v=356a192b HTTP/2.0" 200 1135 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; rv:123.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/123.0"
Mar 20 12:36:33 cyan reverse-proxy[2878]: 172.71.103.106 - - [20/Mar/2024:12:36:33 +0000] "GET /apps/theming/theme/dark-highcontrast.css?plain=1&v=356a192b HTTP/2.0" 200 1166 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; rv:123.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/123.0"
Mar 20 12:36:33 cyan reverse-proxy[2878]: 172.71.95.22 - - [20/Mar/2024:12:36:33 +0000] "GET /apps/theming/theme/dark.css?plain=1&v=356a192b HTTP/2.0" 200 1078 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; rv:123.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/123.0"
Mar 20 12:36:42 cyan reverse-proxy[2878]: 172.71.98.156 - - [20/Mar/2024:12:36:42 +0000] "POST /login/v2/poll HTTP/2.0" 404 2 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux) mirall/3.12.0git (Nextcloud, arch-6.6.19-1-lts ClientArchitecture: x86_64 OsArchitecture: x86_64)"
Mar 20 12:36:43 cyan reverse-proxy[2878]: 172.71.98.156 - - [20/Mar/2024:12:36:43 +0000] "POST /login/v2/poll HTTP/2.0" 404 2 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux) mirall/3.12.0git (Nextcloud, arch-6.6.19-1-lts ClientArchitecture: x86_64 OsArchitecture: x86_64)"
Mar 20 12:37:39 cyan reverse-proxy[2878]: 172.71.99.54 - - [20/Mar/2024:12:37:39 +0000] "GET / HTTP/2.0" 404 20 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:123.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/123.0"
Mar 20 12:37:40 cyan reverse-proxy[2878]: 172.71.98.139 - - [20/Mar/2024:12:37:40 +0000] "GET /index.php/apps/files/preview-service-worker.js HTTP/2.0" 404 20 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:123.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/123.0"
Mar 20 12:38:27 cyan reverse-proxy[2878]: 172.71.99.32 - - [20/Mar/2024:12:38:27 +0000] "GET / HTTP/2.0" 404 20 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:123.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/123.0"
Mar 20 12:38:28 cyan reverse-proxy[2878]: 172.71.99.32 - - [20/Mar/2024:12:38:28 +0000] "GET / HTTP/2.0" 404 20 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:123.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/123.0"
Mar 20 12:38:29 cyan reverse-proxy[2878]: 172.71.99.32 - - [20/Mar/2024:12:38:29 +0000] "GET / HTTP/2.0" 404 20 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:123.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/123.0"
Mar 20 12:41:21 cyan reverse-proxy[2878]: 172.71.102.48 - - [20/Mar/2024:12:41:21 +0000] "GET /hosting/capabilities HTTP/2.0" 404 68 "-" "Nextcloud Server Crawler"
Mar 20 12:45:16 cyan reverse-proxy[2878]: 172.71.102.130 - - [20/Mar/2024:12:45:16 +0000] "GET / HTTP/2.0" 404 20 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:123.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/123.0"
Mar 20 12:45:17 cyan reverse-proxy[2878]: 172.71.98.139 - - [20/Mar/2024:12:45:17 +0000] "GET /index.php/apps/files/preview-service-worker.js HTTP/2.0" 404 20 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:123.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/123.0"
Mar 20 12:45:20 cyan reverse-proxy[2878]: 172.71.102.130 - - [20/Mar/2024:12:45:20 +0000] "GET / HTTP/2.0" 404 20 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:123.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/123.0"
Mar 20 12:45:28 cyan reverse-proxy[2878]: 78.153.140.179 - - [20/Mar/2024:12:45:28 +0000] "GET /.env HTTP/1.1" 400 650 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.129 Safari/537.36"
Mar 20 12:46:44 cyan reverse-proxy[2878]: 172.71.98.20 - - [20/Mar/2024:12:46:44 +0000] "GET /index.php/204 HTTP/2.0" 404 20 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Android) Nextcloud-android/3.28.0"
Mar 20 12:45:16 cyan reverse-proxy[2878]: 172.71.102.130 - - [20/Mar/2024:12:45:16 +0000] "GET / HTTP/2.0" 404 20 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:123.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/123.0"
Mar 20 12:45:17 cyan reverse-proxy[2878]: 172.71.98.139 - - [20/Mar/2024:12:45:17 +0000] "GET /index.php/apps/files/preview-service-worker.js HTTP/2.0" 404 20 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:123.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/123.0"
Mar 20 12:45:20 cyan reverse-proxy[2878]: 172.71.102.130 - - [20/Mar/2024:12:45:20 +0000] "GET / HTTP/2.0" 404 20 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:123.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/123.0"
Mar 20 12:45:28 cyan reverse-proxy[2878]: 78.153.140.179 - - [20/Mar/2024:12:45:28 +0000] "GET /.env HTTP/1.1" 400 650 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.129 Safari/537.36"
Mar 20 12:46:44 cyan reverse-proxy[2878]: 172.71.98.20 - - [20/Mar/2024:12:46:44 +0000] "GET /index.php/204 HTTP/2.0" 404 20 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Android) Nextcloud-android/3.28.0"
Mar 20 12:45:16 cyan reverse-proxy[2878]: 172.71.102.130 - - [20/Mar/2024:12:45:16 +0000] "GET / HTTP/2.0" 404 20 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:123.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/123.0"
Mar 20 12:45:17 cyan reverse-proxy[2878]: 172.71.98.139 - - [20/Mar/2024:12:45:17 +0000] "GET /index.php/apps/files/preview-service-worker.js HTTP/2.0" 404 20 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:123.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/123.0"
Mar 20 12:45:20 cyan reverse-proxy[2878]: 172.71.102.130 - - [20/Mar/2024:12:45:20 +0000] "GET / HTTP/2.0" 404 20 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:123.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/123.0"
Mar 20 12:45:28 cyan reverse-proxy[2878]: 78.153.140.179 - - [20/Mar/2024:12:45:28 +0000] "GET /.env HTTP/1.1" 400 650 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.129 Safari/537.36"
Mar 20 12:46:44 cyan reverse-proxy[2878]: 172.71.98.20 - - [20/Mar/2024:12:46:44 +0000] "GET /index.php/204 HTTP/2.0" 404 20 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Android) Nextcloud-android/3.28.0"
```

*podman-nextcloud-web.log (Nextcloud web server)*

```
-- Boot 1d3092f508084a6ea6c9b197802b6781 --
Mar 20 12:35:48 cyan systemd[1]: Starting podman-nextcloud-web.service...
[...]
Mar 20 12:35:51 cyan systemd[1]: Started podman-nextcloud-web.service.
[...]
Mar 20 12:35:51 cyan nextcloud-web[3139]: /docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
Mar 20 12:35:51 cyan nextcloud-web[3139]: 2024/03/20 12:35:51 [warn] 1#1: duplicate extension "js", content type: "text/javascript", previous content type: "application/javascript" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/sites-enabled/nc.meinel.link.conf:32
Mar 20 12:35:51 cyan nextcloud-web[3139]: nginx: [warn] duplicate extension "js", content type: "text/javascript", previous content type: "application/javascript" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/sites-enabled/nc.meinel.link.conf:32
Mar 20 12:36:28 cyan nextcloud-web[3139]: 127.0.0.1 - - [20/Mar/2024:12:36:28 +0000] "GET /index.php/204 HTTP/1.1" 204 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux) mirall/3.12.0git (Nextcloud, arch-6.6.19-1-lts ClientArchitecture: x86_64 OsArchitecture: x86_64)"
Mar 20 12:36:28 cyan nextcloud-web[3139]: 127.0.0.1 - - [20/Mar/2024:12:36:28 +0000] "GET /index.php/204 HTTP/1.1" 204 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux) mirall/3.12.0git (Nextcloud, arch-6.6.19-1-lts ClientArchitecture: x86_64 OsArchitecture: x86_64)"
Mar 20 12:36:28 cyan nextcloud-web[3139]: 127.0.0.1 - - [20/Mar/2024:12:36:28 +0000] "GET /status.php HTTP/1.1" 200 151 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux) mirall/3.12.0git (Nextcloud, arch-6.6.19-1-lts ClientArchitecture: x86_64 OsArchitecture: x86_64)"
Mar 20 12:36:28 cyan nextcloud-web[3139]: 127.0.0.1 - - [20/Mar/2024:12:36:28 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 5 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux) mirall/3.12.0git (Nextcloud, arch-6.6.19-1-lts ClientArchitecture: x86_64 OsArchitecture: x86_64)"
Mar 20 12:36:28 cyan nextcloud-web[3139]: 127.0.0.1 - - [20/Mar/2024:12:36:28 +0000] "GET /ocs/v2.php/cloud/capabilities?format=json HTTP/1.1" 200 368 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux) mirall/3.12.0git (Nextcloud, arch-6.6.19-1-lts ClientArchitecture: x86_64 OsArchitecture: x86_64)"
Mar 20 12:36:28 cyan nextcloud-web[3139]: 127.0.0.1 - - [20/Mar/2024:12:36:28 +0000] "PROPFIND /remote.php/dav/files/leo/ HTTP/1.1" 401 569 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux) mirall/3.12.0git (Nextcloud, arch-6.6.19-1-lts ClientArchitecture: x86_64 OsArchitecture: x86_64)"
Mar 20 12:36:28 cyan nextcloud-web[3139]: 127.0.0.1 - - [20/Mar/2024:12:36:28 +0000] "GET /login HTTP/1.1" 200 5230 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux) mirall/3.12.0git (Nextcloud, arch-6.6.19-1-lts ClientArchitecture: x86_64 OsArchitecture: x86_64)"
Mar 20 12:36:29 cyan nextcloud-web[3139]: 127.0.0.1 - - [20/Mar/2024:12:36:29 +0000] "POST /index.php/login/v2 HTTP/1.1" 200 320 "-" "tulip (Desktop Client - Linux)"
Mar 20 12:36:32 cyan nextcloud-web[3139]: 127.0.0.1 - - [20/Mar/2024:12:36:32 +0000] "GET /login/v2/flow/ChPehj88Ez6kzHrrfrcHMM572RXtgtl1IohaqeJr8ObTQq40yyV9xx0NbmRwEqmhmyqMOPB3owFWjZlcXGbHhpTztZpkb6KGWC8suDWhq6Hy6R2OjJU5jYdKAcWJzrh6 HTTP/1.1" 303 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; rv:123.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/123.0"
Mar 20 12:36:32 cyan nextcloud-web[3139]: 127.0.0.1 - - [20/Mar/2024:12:36:32 +0000] "GET /login/v2/flow?user= HTTP/1.1" 200 7163 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; rv:123.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/123.0"
Mar 20 12:36:32 cyan nextcloud-web[3139]: 127.0.0.1 - - [20/Mar/2024:12:36:32 +0000] "GET /apps/theming/theme/default.css?plain=1&v=356a192b HTTP/1.1" 200 1099 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; rv:123.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/123.0"
Mar 20 12:36:32 cyan nextcloud-web[3139]: 127.0.0.1 - - [20/Mar/2024:12:36:32 +0000] "GET /apps/theming/theme/light.css?plain=1&v=356a192b HTTP/1.1" 200 1099 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; rv:123.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/123.0"
Mar 20 12:36:32 cyan nextcloud-web[3139]: 127.0.0.1 - - [20/Mar/2024:12:36:32 +0000] "GET /apps/theming/theme/opendyslexic.css?plain=0&v=356a192b HTTP/1.1" 200 348 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; rv:123.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/123.0"
Mar 20 12:36:32 cyan nextcloud-web[3139]: 127.0.0.1 - - [20/Mar/2024:12:36:32 +0000] "GET /apps/theming/theme/light-highcontrast.css?plain=0&v=356a192b HTTP/1.1" 200 1171 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; rv:123.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/123.0"
Mar 20 12:36:32 cyan nextcloud-web[3139]: 127.0.0.1 - - [20/Mar/2024:12:36:32 +0000] "GET /apps/theming/theme/dark-highcontrast.css?plain=0&v=356a192b HTTP/1.1" 200 1202 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; rv:123.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/123.0"
Mar 20 12:36:32 cyan nextcloud-web[3139]: 127.0.0.1 - - [20/Mar/2024:12:36:32 +0000] "GET /apps/theming/theme/dark.css?plain=0&v=356a192b HTTP/1.1" 200 1110 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; rv:123.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/123.0"
Mar 20 12:36:32 cyan nextcloud-web[3139]: 127.0.0.1 - - [20/Mar/2024:12:36:32 +0000] "GET /apps/theming/theme/light.css?plain=0&v=356a192b HTTP/1.1" 200 1123 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; rv:123.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/123.0"
Mar 20 12:36:33 cyan nextcloud-web[3139]: 127.0.0.1 - - [20/Mar/2024:12:36:33 +0000] "GET /apps/theming/theme/light-highcontrast.css?plain=1&v=356a192b HTTP/1.1" 200 1147 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; rv:123.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/123.0"
Mar 20 12:36:33 cyan nextcloud-web[3139]: 127.0.0.1 - - [20/Mar/2024:12:36:33 +0000] "GET /apps/theming/theme/dark-highcontrast.css?plain=1&v=356a192b HTTP/1.1" 200 1178 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; rv:123.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/123.0"
Mar 20 12:36:33 cyan nextcloud-web[3139]: 127.0.0.1 - - [20/Mar/2024:12:36:33 +0000] "GET /apps/theming/theme/dark.css?plain=1&v=356a192b HTTP/1.1" 200 1090 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; rv:123.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/123.0"
Mar 20 12:36:42 cyan nextcloud-web[3139]: 127.0.0.1 - - [20/Mar/2024:12:36:42 +0000] "POST /login/v2/poll HTTP/1.1" 404 2 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux) mirall/3.12.0git (Nextcloud, arch-6.6.19-1-lts ClientArchitecture: x86_64 OsArchitecture: x86_64)"
Mar 20 12:36:43 cyan nextcloud-web[3139]: 127.0.0.1 - - [20/Mar/2024:12:36:43 +0000] "POST /login/v2/poll HTTP/1.1" 404 2 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux) mirall/3.12.0git (Nextcloud, arch-6.6.19-1-lts ClientArchitecture: x86_64 OsArchitecture: x86_64)"
```

*podman-nextcloud-app.log (Nextcloud app)*

```
-- Boot 1d3092f508084a6ea6c9b197802b6781 --
Mar 20 12:35:48 cyan systemd[1]: Starting podman-nextcloud-app.service...
[...]
Mar 20 12:35:51 cyan systemd[1]: Started podman-nextcloud-app.service.
Mar 20 12:35:51 cyan nextcloud-app[3135]: Configuring Redis as session handler
[...]
Mar 20 12:35:51 cyan nextcloud-app[3135]: Initializing nextcloud 28.0.3.2 ...
Mar 20 12:35:51 cyan nextcloud-app[3135]: Upgrading nextcloud from 27.1.6.2 ...
[...]
Mar 20 12:36:17 cyan nextcloud-app[3135]: Update successful
Mar 20 12:36:17 cyan nextcloud-app[3135]: Turned off maintenance mode
[...]
Mar 20 12:36:17 cyan nextcloud-app[3135]: .htaccess has been updated
[...]
Mar 20 12:36:18 cyan nextcloud-app[3135]: [20-Mar-2024 12:36:18] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
Mar 20 12:36:28 cyan nextcloud-app[3135]: 127.0.0.1 -  20/Mar/2024:12:36:27 +0000 "GET /index.php" 204
Mar 20 12:36:28 cyan nextcloud-app[3135]: 127.0.0.1 -  20/Mar/2024:12:36:28 +0000 "GET /index.php" 204
Mar 20 12:36:28 cyan nextcloud-app[3135]: 127.0.0.1 -  20/Mar/2024:12:36:28 +0000 "GET /status.php" 200
Mar 20 12:36:28 cyan nextcloud-app[3135]: 127.0.0.1 -  20/Mar/2024:12:36:28 +0000 "GET /index.php" 302
Mar 20 12:36:28 cyan nextcloud-app[3135]: 127.0.0.1 -  20/Mar/2024:12:36:28 +0000 "GET /ocs/v2.php" 200
Mar 20 12:36:28 cyan nextcloud-app[3135]: 127.0.0.1 -  20/Mar/2024:12:36:28 +0000 "PROPFIND /remote.php" 401
Mar 20 12:36:28 cyan nextcloud-app[3135]: 127.0.0.1 -  20/Mar/2024:12:36:28 +0000 "GET /index.php" 200
Mar 20 12:36:29 cyan nextcloud-app[3135]: 127.0.0.1 -  20/Mar/2024:12:36:29 +0000 "POST /index.php" 200
Mar 20 12:36:32 cyan nextcloud-app[3135]: 127.0.0.1 -  20/Mar/2024:12:36:32 +0000 "GET /index.php" 303
Mar 20 12:36:32 cyan nextcloud-app[3135]: 127.0.0.1 -  20/Mar/2024:12:36:32 +0000 "GET /index.php" 200
Mar 20 12:36:32 cyan nextcloud-app[3135]: 127.0.0.1 -  20/Mar/2024:12:36:32 +0000 "GET /index.php" 200
Mar 20 12:36:32 cyan nextcloud-app[3135]: 127.0.0.1 -  20/Mar/2024:12:36:32 +0000 "GET /index.php" 200
Mar 20 12:36:32 cyan nextcloud-app[3135]: 127.0.0.1 -  20/Mar/2024:12:36:32 +0000 "GET /index.php" 200
Mar 20 12:36:32 cyan nextcloud-app[3135]: 127.0.0.1 -  20/Mar/2024:12:36:32 +0000 "GET /index.php" 200
Mar 20 12:36:32 cyan nextcloud-app[3135]: 127.0.0.1 -  20/Mar/2024:12:36:32 +0000 "GET /index.php" 200
Mar 20 12:36:32 cyan nextcloud-app[3135]: 127.0.0.1 -  20/Mar/2024:12:36:32 +0000 "GET /index.php" 200
Mar 20 12:36:32 cyan nextcloud-app[3135]: 127.0.0.1 -  20/Mar/2024:12:36:32 +0000 "GET /index.php" 200
Mar 20 12:36:33 cyan nextcloud-app[3135]: 127.0.0.1 -  20/Mar/2024:12:36:33 +0000 "GET /index.php" 200
Mar 20 12:36:33 cyan nextcloud-app[3135]: 127.0.0.1 -  20/Mar/2024:12:36:33 +0000 "GET /index.php" 200
Mar 20 12:36:33 cyan nextcloud-app[3135]: 127.0.0.1 -  20/Mar/2024:12:36:33 +0000 "GET /index.php" 200
Mar 20 12:36:42 cyan nextcloud-app[3135]: 127.0.0.1 -  20/Mar/2024:12:36:42 +0000 "POST /index.php" 404
Mar 20 12:36:43 cyan nextcloud-app[3135]: 127.0.0.1 -  20/Mar/2024:12:36:43 +0000 "POST /index.php" 404
```

## What I tried to solve/"debug" this

So far I have inspected the logs and tried to find out more about why I am encountering this problem.

I did some research online to find similar problems, which wasn't successful. I also searched for similar setups and found some. [This](https://kennydodrill.com/blog/using-podman-to-set-up-a-php-development-environment/) is an example.

Comment: Very odd - particulary `404` errors in the proxy. If it can't contact the application server I would expect a `500` or similar. I think you are probably going to have to get shell access and find a way to run requests from the various containers one-by-one and see where things break. If curl/wget/python+libs isn't available in the containers you can open tcp connections purely with bash if you have to.#

Comment: @RichardHuxton Thanks for the answer! The `404` error is indeed very weird.

To test this, I disabled the systemd services for the nextcloud-fpm image, which also resulted in a `404`.
Afterwards I set up a podman container (not using nextcloud-fpm but php-fpm and an index.php containing `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`) that is handled in the same way.
Multiple connections to that container over a period of 10mins succeed, which never happened with the Nextcloud container.

After disabling that container I also get the expected `502`, not the weird `404`.

Comment: I'll do some further testing, as you have suggested and post any updates here.

If I execute `curl -L https://nc.meinel.link (Nextcloud)` I get an empty response (no error) if it is disabled.
If I execute `curl -L https://office.meinel.link (php-fpm)` I get a 502 error if it is disabled, otherwise I get a page.

This behaviour is the same on the host system and my laptop.

Comment: On other systems that aren't in the same network as I am using different DNS servers etc., the behaviour is also the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more testing and considering what could be at fault here I noticed that port 8082, which should be available for nextcloud is used by another service (probably gitlab).

I was almost 100% certain, that I have updated all the ports to not conflict with each other, but it seems like whatever service caused that, just occupied that port anyways.

I also tested port 8082 and 8083 before with the same error, which is why this was even more confusing. Now using different ports, it works totally fine.

This also explains the delay where the website was accessible and why the website didn't work after a reload.

Comment: Nice to see a solution. Good trouble-shooting.